# Error here: 'Employee' does not refer to a value

Tags: xcode, class, compiler-errors

I'm working on a programming assignment and I have 9 of the same errors. All that say 'Employee' does not refer to value. Can someone please help me?! Thanks so much in advance. Below is where I'm getting the errors and then I have also included my class. ![enter image description here][1]

Class:

```
#ifndef Programming_Assignment__3_employee_h
#define Programming_Assignment__3_employee_h

#include <string>

class Employee
{
  private:
  int ID;
  std::string ssn;
  std::string emailaddress;
  int yearOfbirth;

 public:
  static std::string name;
  Employee();
  int  displayRecord();
  void addEmployee();
  int GetID();
  std::string GetEmail();

};



#endif
```

Errors:

```
int  displayRecord(vector <Employee*> input)
{
    cout << " ______________________________";

    for ( int count = 0; count < 200; count ++)
    {
        std::getline(Employee.name);


        cout << setw(5) << Employee.ID << setw(15) << Employee.name << setw(15) << setw(15) <<      Employee.emailAddress << setw(8)<< Employee.yearOfBirth;
     }
  }

void addemployee(vector <Employee*> input)
{
    cout << "Employee ID : " << endl;
    cin >> Employee.ID;
    cout << "Employee Name: ";
    cin>> Employee[input].name;
    cout << "SSN :";
    cin >> Employee[input].ssn;
    cout << "Email Address: ";
    cin >> Employee[input].emailAddress;
    cout << "Birth Year: ";
    cin >> Employee[input].yearOfBirth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring "class Employee" merely defines the structure of the class. It does not allocate any memory to store its values. You need to allocate an instance of the class somewhere.

Edit:

Actually the instance(s) are passed into the functions through the input variable. You need to access those instances (not the class) in your cin and cout statements.